# valueChanges respond only from the second touch

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

In reactive form, I am using mat-select in a FormArray, for reason that I didn't understand the valueChange response only in the second touch.

this is the method that I am using:

```
  doSomething(i) {
   this.form.at(i).valueChanges.pipe(switchMap((categoryId: any) => {
      return this.service.getDataByCategoryTypeAndProperty(categoryId, this.propertyId)
    })).subscribe(data =>{
      this.gatData = data
   })
  }



  <mat-form-field >
    <mat-label>Service </mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="categoryId" (selectionChange)="doSomething(i)" >
      <mat-option *ngFor="let category of Categories" [value]="category.categoryId">{{category.categoryName}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

my question is how valueChanges will respond from the first touch,
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to mix events with valuechanges. Do either.

Keeping the event looks like this:

```
doSomething(i) {
   this.service.getDataByCategoryTypeAndProperty(this.form.at(i).value, this.propertyId)
    .pipe(take(1))
    .subscribe(data => this.gatData = data);
}
```

For keeping the valuechanges, you set up the valuechanges subscription once after init of the form, e.g. in ngOnInit.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because you're subscribing to the `valueChanges` `Obsevable` only when `selectionChange` event is fired. Then, in the next change the desired action in the subscription callback occours.

Instead, you need to subscribe to `valueChanges` right after you create your form. In this way, you'll be able to see your changes subscription effect right on the first change.

No need for the `selectionChange` listener at all, since you're already listening to the form changes.

On the other hand, if you insist to use the `selectionChange` event, you can use it by itself only and do your action on `doSomething` without subscribing to `valueChanges`, but then you will loose all the `rxjs` logic benefits - such the `pipe` you're using there.